# How to launch terminal or command window on program run in IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm writing a command line program and want the terminal to automatically open whenever I run my program is this possible in IntelliJ?

Comment: It depends. How do you run it? E.g. you can configure the [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) that executes the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Use this code (you'll need a `Project` instance, you can get it from `ActionEvent.getProject`):

```
GeneralCommandLine commandLine = new GeneralCommandLine([List of your command line arguments]);
OSProcessHandler handler = new OSProcessHandler(commandLine);
TextConsoleBuilder consoleBuilder = TextConsoleBuilderFactory.getInstance().createBuilder(project);
ConsoleView console = consoleBuilder.getConsole();
Executor executor = DefaultRunExecutor.getRunExecutorInstance();
DefaultActionGroup actionGroup = new DefaultActionGroup();
BorderLayoutPanel component = JBUI.Panels.simplePanel();
component = component.addToCenter(console.getComponent());
ActionToolbar toolbar = ActionManager.getInstance().createActionToolbar("MainToolbar", actionGroup, false);
RunContentDescriptor descriptor = new RunContentDescriptor(console,
        handler,
        component.addToLeft(toolbar.getComponent()),
        [Your title],
        [Your icon]);
ExecutionManager manager = ExecutionManager.getInstance(project);
manager.getContentManager().showRunContent(executor, descriptor);
AnAction[] consoleActions = console.createConsoleActions();

for (AnAction action : consoleActions) actionGroup.add(action);

actionGroup.add(new PinActiveTabAction());
actionGroup.add(new CloseAction(executor, descriptor, project));
console.allowHeavyFilters();
console.attachToProcess(handler);
ProcessTerminatedListener.attach(handler);
handler.startNotify();
```

Comment: oh I meant the osx terminal using some sort of config for intelliJ, I know some IDEs have this and I thought IntelliJ might too

Comment: What do you mean by "osx terminal **using some sort of config**"